# How can I concatenate several variables to a command and execute it?

Tags: bash, cmake

For building applications I use CMake.
I parse my CMake command in a script with several variables:

```
CMAKE_COMMAND=" \
$CMAKE \
-G "$Build_TOOL_CMAKE" \
[...]"
```

After parsing that command I print it with `printf` for control:

```
printf "\n${CMAKE_COMMAND}\n"
```

And then I eventually execute the command with:

```
$CMAKE_COMMAND
```

This script worked as long as I had "Ninja" as Generator (the `-G` option -->  `BUILD_TOOL_CMAKE="Ninja"`) as it does have no space characters in it.

Now I want to use "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" as Generator. I tried several ways of escaping the space characters, e.g.:

```
CMAKE_COMMAND=" \
$CMAKE \
-G \"$Build_TOOL_CMAKE\" \
[...]"
```

or

```
CMAKE_COMMAND=" \
$CMAKE \
-G '$Build_TOOL_CMAKE' \
[...]"
```

The printed command became correct in some cases, but the execution of it resulted in errors like:

> CMake Error: Could not create named generator Eclipse

or

> CMake Error: Could not create named generator "Eclipse

This leads to the assumption that something is wrong with escaping the spaces, but the `printf` works:

```
cmake.exe -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -S sourcefolder -B buildfolder # printf $CMAKE_COMMAND
```

Did I miss something? Maybe the executing merely by the variable (`$CMAKE_COMMAND`) is also the wrong approach.

Comment: This does not help me. I dont use xargs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CMake's `configure_file` command: [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html)

Place all the variables in `command.in` and write it to `command`.

```
configure_file(command.in, command)
```

The file `command.in` can looks like this:

```
${CMAKE_COMMAND} -G ${Build_TOOL_CMAKE}
```

Comment: I don't know where to put this. I can't touch the CMakeLists.txt